# Product and category url rewrite concept

Tags: catalog, category, url-rewrite

I have a confusion in product and category **url** rewrite concept. Is magento stores the url in database? If yes which table? If no how we get the category and product url from collections? like this.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 16)
    ->addUrlRewrite();
$product_collection_url = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
```

and what is `addUrlRewrite()` ?
Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

These questions might help to explain it:

- [$_product->getProductUrl() giving url path without URL key](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14458/product-getproducturl-giving-url-path-without-url-key)
- [Magento getProductUrl() is not returning the right url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997108/magento-getproducturl-is-not-returning-the-right-url)

Without `addUrlRewrite` you may get the URLs in the form of `http://www.my site.com/catalog/product/view/id/2309/s/shopcat/category/373/` which don't look very nice!

`addUrlRewrite` gives the URL in the form with the URL key, eg. `http://www.site.com/product-url-key.html`.

Adding a category ID eg. `addUrlRewrite(15)` gives the category URL for that product, eg. `http://www.site.com/category-15/product-url-key.html`, providing the product is in that category of course!

The latter will only work if in System/Configuration/Catalog/Search Engine Optimization you have `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` set to Yes and `Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products` set to No. See here for more on that http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/canonical-meta-tag

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Sarah.. So the url key is stored in table right ..? which table ..?

Comment: You can see the URL key when you go into a product in the admin panel, it is one of the attributes listed (under "Status"). The URL rewrites are stored in Catalog/Url Rewrite Management too. I am not sure about the DB tables but this may help http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/246103/ Would recommend sticking to the admin panel where you can though because there are a lot of tables involved with Magento products.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi this is the example you can display the Url of Product.

         $listInstance = Mage:getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list');

         $_productCollection =  $listInstance ->getLoadedProductCollection();

        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
{

       echo $_product->getProductUrl();// product Url
 }
```